# Why doesn't the operator module have a function for logical or?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitwise-operators

In Python 3, operator.or_ is equivalent to the bitwise `|`, not the logical `or`. Why is there no operator for the logical `or`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `or` and `and` operators can't be expressed as functions because of their [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) behavior:

```
False and some_function()
True or some_function()
```

in these cases, `some_function()` is never called.

A hypothetical `or_(True, some_function())`, on the other hand, would have to call `some_function()`, because function arguments are always evaluated before the function is called.

Answer (score 9):

The logical or is a *control structure* - it decides whether code is being executed. Consider

```
1 or 1/0
```

This does **not** throw an error.

In contrast, the following **does** throw an error, no matter how the function is implemented:

```
def logical_or(a, b):
  return a or b
logical_or(1, 1/0)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind the lack of short circuiting behaviour mentioned by others; you could try the below code.

`all([a, b]) == (a and b)`

`any([a, b]) == (a or b)`

They both accept a single collection (such as a list, tuple and even a generator) with 2 or more elements so the following is also valid:

`all([a, b, c]) == (a and b and c)`

For more details have a look at the documentation in question:
http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#all

Comment: -1 for TWO reasons: (1) `99 or 88` -> `99` but `any([99, 88])` -> `True` (2) `any` and `all` DO short_circuit; given `def foo(): yield 1; yield 0; yield 1/0` then `all(foo())` -> `False` and `any(foo))` -> `True`

Comment: I should have been clearer but I meant each of the a, b and c to represent simple expressions with a boolean result such as: `1 < 2` which would mean they are evaluated before. I always forget about the other meaning of `or`.

Comment: Python `or` has only one meaning. Your answer provides only a clumsy way of using `all/any` instead of `&/|` -- not what the OP wants.

Comment: @John-Machin Well there are two meanings: `5 or 6` has the result of `5` which isn't exactly boolean logic like `True or False`. Good point it does look like I mean the functions don't short circuit, I'll edit the answer. However I think this could be useful if you wanted to pass around references to logical operators, I've found occasion to do the same thing with numerical operators before.