# Multi-argument null coalesce and built-in "or" function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nonetype, null-coalescing-operator, null-coalescing

Python has a great syntax for null coalescing:

```
c = a or b
```

This sets `c` to `a` if `a` is not `False`, `None`, empty, or `0`, otherwise `c` is set to `b`.

(Yes, *technically* this is not null coalescing, it's more like `bool` coalescing, but it's close enough for the purpose of this question.)

There is not an obvious way to do this for a collection of objects, so I wrote a function to do this:

```
from functools import reduce

def or_func(x, y):
    return x or y

def null_coalesce(*a):
    return reduce(or_func, a)
```

This works, but writing my own `or_func` seems suboptimal - surely there is a built-in like `__or__`? I've attempted to use [`object.__or__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__or__#object.__or__) and [`operator.__or__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html?highlight=__or__#operator.__or__), but the first gives an `AttributeError` and the second refers to the bitwise `|` (or) operator.

As a result I have two questions:

1. Is there a built-in function which acts like `a or b`?
2. Is there a built-in implementation of such a null coalesce function?

The answer to both seems to be no, but that would be somewhat surprising to me.

Comment: None-coalescing, -aware, -safe operators is proposed on [PEP 505](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0505/) which has deferred status.

Comment: @alkasm nope, that's the bitwise OR operator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not exactly a single built-in, but what you want to achieve can be easily done with:

```
def null_coalesce(*a):
    return next(x for x in a if x)
```

It's lazy, so it does short-circuit like `a or b or c`, but unlike `reduce`.

You can also make it null-specific with:

```
def null_coalesce(*a):
    return next(x for x in a if x is not None)
```

Comment: `null_coalesce([0,0,3]) == [0, 0, 3]` What's going on there?

Comment: @wjandrea it's star-args, not a single arg. You should be passing `0, 0, 3` to the function, not `[0, 0, 3]` if you want to just return 3.

Comment: @alkasm ohhh, oops

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a built-in function which I can use which acts like a or b?

No. Quoting from [this answer on why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7894752/3889449):

> The `or` and `and` operators can't be expressed as functions because of their [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) behavior:
>
> ```
> False and some_function()
> True or some_function()
> ```
>
> in these cases, `some_function()` is never called.
>
> A hypothetical `or_(True, some_function())`, on the other hand, would have to call `some_function()`, because function arguments are always evaluated before the function is called.

---

> Is there a built-in implementation of such a null coalesce function?

No, there isn't. However, [the Python documentation page for `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) suggests the following:

```
def first_true(iterable, default=False, pred=None):
    """Returns the first true value in the iterable.

    If no true value is found, returns *default*

    If *pred* is not None, returns the first item
    for which pred(item) is true.

    """
    # first_true([a,b,c], x) --> a or b or c or x
    # first_true([a,b], x, f) --> a if f(a) else b if f(b) else x
    return next(filter(pred, iterable), default)
```

Comment: Alternatively, `operator.or_`

Comment: @alkasm `operator.__or__` and `operator.or_` are for bitwise OR. That's another thing. I quickly edited my answer after noticing.

Comment: The ability to have a predicate in this is really nice +1

Comment: Oops! Good call!

Answer (score 1):

Marco has it right, there's no built-in, and itertools has a recipe. You can also `pip install boltons` to use the [`boltons.iterutils.first()`](https://boltons.readthedocs.io/en/latest/iterutils.html#boltons.iterutils.first) utility, which is perfect if you want short-circuiting.

```py
from boltons.iterutils import first

c = first([a, b])
```

There are a few other related and handy [reduction tools in `iterutils`](https://boltons.readthedocs.io/en/latest/iterutils.html#reduction), too, like `one()`.

I've done enough of the above that I actually ended up wanting a higher-level tool that could capture the entire interaction (including the `a` and `b` references) in a Python data structure, yielding [`glom`](https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and its [`Coalesce`](https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#conditional-access-and-defaults-with-coalesce) functionality.

```py
from glom import glom, Coalesce

target = {'b': 1}
spec = Coalesce('a', 'b')

c = glom(target, spec)
# c = 1
```

(Full disclosure, as hinted above, I maintain `glom` and `boltons`, which is good news, because [you can bug me](https://github.com/mahmoud/glom/issues) if you find bugs.)