# How could I get a conditional operator inserted by the user

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-statements, operators

I need to do a conditional statement in Python with an operator (or, and) insert by the user. Example:

```py
a = 1
b = 1
c = 1
operator = input("Type the operator: ")
if(a == b operator b == c):
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

I know, I can do it using if inside if. But I wanna know other way to do it.

Comment: No, this is not possible. The only way I can think of it is to create a complete condition with eval ().

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

There is a library called operator!

```
import operator

ops = { "|": operator.or_, "&": operator.and_}

operator = input("Type the operator: ")

if(ops[operator](a == b, b == c):
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Lookup table idea is from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740726/turn-string-into-operator).

Unfortunately, it does only work for bitwise operators. There are no and/or logical operators in the library.

Comment: If you're curious why the logical `and` and `or` aren't there, [here's the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7894752/10077).

Answer (score -1):

You can use eval() function to do this.

```
a = 1
b = 1
c = 1
operator = input("Type the operator: ")
exp = f"a == b {operator} b == c"
if eval(exp):
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```